# How to bind data with Enable Property?

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net

How can i enabled/disable server control using `Eval('bindata')`?

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtRemarks" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("Remarks") %>'    
    CssClass="remarkstest"  Enabled="'<%#Eval("IsSundayChangable") %>'"></asp:TextBox>
```

Comment: I have try it but its not working Thank for reply

Comment: I have try with Enabled='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "IsSundayChangable")%>' it works fine for drop down but not textbox

Answer (score 0):

try something like this:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtRemarks" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("Remarks") %>'    CssClass="remarkstest"  <%# GetStatus(Container.DataItem)%> ></asp:TextBox>


    protected string GetStatus(object oItem)
    {
          return DataBinder.Eval(oItem, "IsSundayChangable").toString()=="false"?"disabled",string.empty;
    }
```